# How to combine speech recognition and pyttsx on python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I am new to python,  and have been learning how to use the python speech recognition "pygsr"  and pyttsx  now I want to know how to combine the codes to achieve a common goal,  which is: when I talk to the program it will give me a response.

I use python 2.7 
On Windows 8
and I have already installed the speech recognition and pyttsx library

This is code pyttsx  code

```
import pyttsx
engine = pyttsx.init ()
engine.say ( 'Good morning.' )
engine.runAndWait ()
```

This is the speech recognition code using python library

```
from pygsr import Pygsr
speech = Pygsr ()
# duration in seconds
speech.record( 3 )
# select the language
phrase, complete_response = speech.s
print phrase
```

Any suggestions on how to get it done is acceptable

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you are looking for is a "dialog manager." A DM listens for instructions and then performs tasks according to the instructions it thinks it hears.
In a really simple implementation you only need an if-then-else-endif type structure; if the user says "count" then the DM knows to count from zero to nine, for example.
A good DM will know what to do if the instruction is not recognized, for example if you cough into the mike. Also while waiting for the next utterance, which it might do in an infinite loop ended when it hears "shut down now", it should use a mechanism that does not put too much burden on your system.
Structured dialog managers can become very complex, and may use advanced techniques of natural language processing (NLP) to manage the "conversation."